# Can someone direct me to prove the following three claims about a rotation group $SO(3)$ and its Lie Algebra?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, rotations

In class my prof made three claims about a group and its Lie algebra. I cannot find direct reference to these claims because they are delivered in verbatim (im not even sure if I have them jogged down 100% correctly). Can someone please help me identify these three properties?

Claim 1: $R\in SO(3)$, so any rotation matrix $R$ is the matrix exponential skew symmetric matrix $M$

Claim 2: Any skew symmetric 3x3 matrix is determined by 3 distinct numbers i.e. a vector

Claim 3: $\omega$ be a vector in $R^3$. Let $v$ = normalized $\omega$ (?) and $\theta$ = length of $\omega$. Then, $\omega$ = $v$ $\theta$. Now, it can be shown that if you take the identity matrix and rotate it by the angle $\theta$ around the axis span{$v$} using the right-hand rule, the result is precisely the matrix $R$

Please direct me to appropriate reference or if these are in fact simple proofs, please show me how these are true. Thank you for your time!

Comment: (1) follows from computing the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$ and using that it is compact; part of this (or at least $O(n)$) is treated, e.g., in Chapter 5 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifold*. For (2), just write down a general $3 \times 3$ skew-symmetric metric and count how many elements you can specify freely. I'm not sure what (3) means exactly, in particular because I don't know what "rotate" the identity matrix means, nor is $R$ specified in this context. It might be best just to ask your professor for the details he has in mind.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have no idea either but some guess: Let $\vec w$ be any vector in $R^3$, and we can define unit vector $\hat v$ = $\vec w$/$|\vec w|$. $\theta$ = length $\vec w$ so that $\vec w$ = $\hat v$  $\theta$. Then $R_{theta,span{v}} I$ = $R$, $R$ any rotation matrix in $SO(3)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's address your questions one at a time. We will start with question 2 since that is the simplest.

$2$. The fact that every skew-symmetric matrix is determined by $3$ numbers is simply the statement that the dimension of the subspace of $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric matrices $\mathrm{Skew}_3$ has dimension $3$. Explicitly, we have the following basis:
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right\},$$
This means that every $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric matrix $A$ can be written in the form
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -c & b \\ c & 0 & -a \\ -b & a & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
In fact, we can say a bit more than this. Every skew-symmetric matrix in fact represents a cross product. Let $\mathbf{v} = (a,\ b,\ c)^\mathrm{T}$ and let $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Then we have
$$A\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{u},$$
which you can verify directly through matrix multiplication. There is in fact a very useful isomorphism between the Lie algebras $(\mathrm{Skew}_3=\mathfrak{so}(3),\ [\cdot,\ \cdot])$ and $(\mathbb{R}^3,\ \times)$ through the above correspondence (where $[\cdot,\ \cdot]$ is the commutator and $\times$ is the cross-product).

Explicitly, let $\Omega: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathfrak{so}(3)$ be given by
$$\Omega(\mathbf{v}) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -c & b \\ c & 0 & -a \\ -b & a & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
where $a,b,c$ are the components of $\mathbf{v}$. Clearly this is an bijection, so we must show that this map preserves the respective products, i.e.
$$[\Omega(\mathbf{u}),\ \Omega(\mathbf{u})] = \Omega(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}).$$
It is simplest to do this by remembering that the action of $\Omega(\mathbf{v})$ on a vector $\mathbf{u}$ is given by the cross product $\Omega(\mathbf{v})\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{u}$ as mentioned earlier. With that in mind, let $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be an arbitrary vector. Then we have
$$\begin{align}\Omega(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v})\mathbf{w} &= (\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v})\times \mathbf{w}\\
&=-(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w})\times\mathbf{u} - (\mathbf{w}\times\mathbf{u})\times\mathbf{v}\\
&=\mathbf{u}\times(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}) - \mathbf{v}\times (\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{w})\\
&=\Omega(\mathbf{u})\Omega(\mathbf{v})\mathbf{w}-\Omega(\mathbf{v})\Omega(\mathbf{u})\mathbf{w}\\
&= [\Omega(\mathbf{u}),\ \Omega(\mathbf{v})]\mathbf{w},\end{align}$$
where in the second step we use the Jacobi identity for the cross product. Since this holds for arbitrary $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}$, we must have 
$$[\Omega(\mathbf{u},\ \Omega(\mathbf{v})] = \Omega(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}).$$
This shows that $\Omega$ is a Lie algebra isomorphism between $(\mathbb{R}^3,\times)$ and $(\mathfrak{so}(3),[\cdot,\ \cdot])$. The existence of this correspondence is precisely the reason why we are able to represent rotations using a single vector, the direction of which represents the action of rotation (with the direction given by the right-hand rule) and the length of which represents the angle of rotation.

Next, let's address your first question.

$1$. There is a well known theorem that the map $\exp : \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow G$ is a surjective map for any compact, connected Lie group $G$. Since $SO(3)$ is compact and connected, this immediately answers your first question (in fact this argument shows that the statement holds true for $SO(n)$ for any $n$). But this theorem is not particularly easy to prove, so let me give a proof specifically for the case of $SO(3)$. In fact, we will do more and give an explicit formula for $\exp: \mathfrak{so}(3)\rightarrow SO(3)$. Let us write elements of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ as we did previously in terms of the parameters $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Theorem:** The matrix exponential $\exp:\mathfrak{so}(3) \rightarrow SO(3)$ is explicitly given by
$$\exp(A) = I + \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}A + \frac{(1-\cos\theta)}{\theta^2}A^2,$$
where $\theta = \sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(A^\mathrm{T}A)} = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$.

**Proof:** Note that we have
$$A^3 = -\theta^2 A$$
for any $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric matrix. This allows us to iteratively determine the remaining powers of $A$ in terms of $A$ and $A^3$, for example:
$$A^4 = -\theta^2 A^2,\ \ A^5 = -\theta^2A^3 = \theta^4 A,\ \ A^6 = -\theta^4 A^2,$$
and in general for $k\ge 0$ we have
$$A^{4k+1} = \theta^{4k}A,\ \ A^{4k+2} = \theta^{4k}A^2,\ \ A^{4k+2} = -\theta^{4k+2}A,\ \ A^{4k+4} = -\theta^{4k+2}A^2$$
Then we can calculate the matrix exponential through the power series:
$$\begin{align} \exp(A) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}\\
&=I + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{A^{4k+1}}{(4k+1)!} + \frac{A^{4k+2}}{(4k+2)!} + \frac{A^{4k+3}}{(4k+3)!} + \frac{A^{4k+4}}{(4k+4)!}\right)\\
&=I + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{\theta}\frac{\theta^{4k+1}}{(4k+1)!}A +\frac{1}{\theta^2}\frac{\theta^{4k+2}}{(4k+2)!}A^2\\ 
&\ \ \ \ \ -\frac{1}{\theta}\frac{\theta^{4k+3}}{(4k+3)!}A - \frac{1}{\theta^2}\frac{\theta^{4k+4}}{(4k+4)!}A^2\bigg)
\end{align}$$
Notice that the even terms in the above sum are precisely the power series for $\frac{1-\cos \theta}{\theta^2}A^2$ and that the odd terms are precisely the power series for $\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}A$. Therefore we must have
$$\exp(A) = I + \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}A + \frac{(1-\cos\theta)}{\theta^2}A^2,$$
as required. $\square$

The above theorem has a nice interpretation, because it is simply the statement of [Rodrigues's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), which shows that the above formula is surjective as a map from $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ to $SO(3)$ (see the link for details).

For your third question, I honestly have no idea what it means to rotate the identity matrix. If you can provide context and information, I'd be happy to provide an answer (assuming I know it of course).

Comment: Wow thank you for your effort! Quick question, what is the applicability of all this? Is it simpler to describe a rotation in the lie algebra of SO(3) instead of SO(3) itself? How do applied mathematician actually use this result?

Comment: Also could you address further the relationship between the commutator and the vector product?

Comment: Indeed this is the idea of the Lie algebra/Lie group correspondence. Many results are simpler to describe using the Lie algebra and can then be lifted to the Lie group. For $SO(3)$, it is simpler to keep track of skew-symmetric matrices (3 numbers) than it is an orthogonal matrix. There are many uses for this result in general. For example, the description of angular momenta and spin in quantum mechanics involves the representation theory of $SO(3)$, which is simplest to describe using the Lie algebra. I'll add a bit on the correspondence between the cross product and commutator in the answer.

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant I've added a bit on the isomorphism between the two Lie algebras.